# How to set readonly field based on two sets of options in InfoPath

Tags: infopath

I'm building an InfoPath form. On the form I have two sets of 2 radio-buttons and I need to set a readonly field based on the state of both sets. What is the best/least effort option todo this? Do I have to create 4 rules and add them to each option? This seems a little heavy handed. Is there any way to do conditional logic in a formula for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfoPath logic is often a bit heavy-handed and not very elegant. If you need four different values in the text field, then you have to create four different rules. As a time saver, you CAN define the rules for one field, then copy all rules and paste them onto the other field. You need to check the field references, though, since IP uses relative references and the "self" field will need correction after pasting.
[image]

:-))))